# Probability of the first transition in k steps

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process, python

How to find the probability of the first transition in $k$ steps from state $i$ to state $j$. Let me remind you of a few formulas.

In zero steps

$$\hat p^{(0)}_{ij}= \begin{cases}
   1 &i = j\\
   0 &i \neq j
 \end{cases}$$
In one step
$$\hat p^{(1)}_{ij}=p_{ij}$$
In two steps
$$\hat p^{(2)}_{ij} = \sum\limits_{m\neq j}p_{im}p_{mj}$$

Recursive formula in $k$ steps

$$\hat p^{(k)}_{ij}=\sum\limits_{m\neq j}p_{im}\hat p^{(k-1)}_{mj}$$

How to implement a program this recursive formula in python. I don't really understand what I should substitute there. In the examples that are in the textbook, the Markov chain consists of three elements and everything is trivially deduced by enumerating all the options. I was given a matrix of transition probabilities $n \times m$, and I don't really understand how I can implement this as a program. (In my case $n = m = 12$)

$$ P = ||p_{ij}|| =  \begin{pmatrix}
  p_{11}& p_{12} & \ldots & p_{1m}\\
  p_{21}& p_{22} & \ldots & p_{2m}\\
  \ldots& \ldots & \ldots & \ldots\\
  p_{n1}& p_{n2} & \ldots & p_{nm}\\
\end{pmatrix} \\ \text{where $p_{ij}$ the probability of transition from state $i$ to state $j$} $$

I see it like this, but this case doesn't seem to work

```
matrix = np.array(...)
sum = 0
def prob(k):
   for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
      for j, element in enumerate(i):
         return matrix[i][j] * prob(k - 1)
sum += prob(9)
```

The task sounds:

> Find the probability of the first transition in 9 steps from state 5 to state 8

Comment: The wording of the Question seems a little odd.  The "probability of the first transition in 9 steps" is perhaps the same as the existence of at least one such transition?  Unless you are trying to find a probability distribution for such a transition in *each* of those first nine steps?  More to the point, one requires the chance of being in the state $i=5$, whereafter the probability of transition to state $j=8$ is given in the matrix.  So perhaps you can clarify what you want (Readers should not be expected to reverse engineer code to understand the real issue).

Comment: @hardmath The task is to find the probability at which there will be a transition to state 8 from state 2 for the first time. The question is how this recursive formula can be applied in practice. Looking at the textbook, it is trivial for me to understand how the process of finding occurs, but looking at the real task, I do not understand how to apply it.

Comment: Do you require a transition *directly* from state 8 to state 2?  Or could the sequence of transitions start from state 1, go after some point to state 8, and then on to state 2 after another indeterminate number of steps?  It is crucial that you clarify exactly what is supposed to happen "for the first time" in order to tell you how that probability is to be determined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, since we do not take into probability of the return to itself, we just need to nullify the transitions of the same name and in the loop raising the transition matrix to the power of the calculated step

```
i = # initial step
j = # final step
k = # necessary step
for s in range(0, k):
    transition_matrix[i][i] = 0
    m = np.linalg.matrix_power(transition_matrix, s+1)
result = m[i][j]
```